# Is Mac OS Big Sur Spying?

Tags: macos, ocsp

I would like to know if macOS "Big Sur" sends unencrypted OCSP requests. I am a newbie and not aware of technical stuff, but when I came across [Jeffrey Paul's article](https://sneak.berlin/20201112/your-computer-isnt-yours/), I am a bit concerned about whether to continue using Mac.

Comment: "unencrypted OCSP requests" does not equal "spying". It's data. "Spying" requires malicious intent.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if macOS "Big Sur" sends unencrypted OCSP requests.

Likely it does. But it is not the fault of MacOS. Instead the OCSP URL in most certificates is HTTP only. Insofar a change to a different OS will not change it. It might change though what certificates are used in the first place. With checking certificates if web sites it likely makes no difference, anf OCSP is often not used in this context anyway. With checks of application signatures it can make a difference - for example Linux based systems usually don't use signed applications in the first place and thus there is also no certificate to check.

> ... but when I came across Jeffrey Paul's article, ...

This article is a bit misleading in that it claims that information about the application used is included in the OCSP request. This is not true. For signed applications (which is what this article is about, not HTTPS in the context of web sites) the OCSP request only includes information about the developer certificate used to sign the application. See [Does Apple really log every app you run? A technical look](https://blog.jacopo.io/en/post/apple-ocsp/).

Answer (score -1):

This article is on iOS and Android but since iOS and MacOS share some stuff you could investigate some of the points in the article further.

https://www.scss.tcd.ie/doug.leith/apple_google.pdf

> "We investigate what data iOS on an iPhone shares with Apple and what
> data Google Android on a Pixel phone shares with Google. We find that
> even when minimally configured and the handset is idle both iOS and
> Google Android share data with Apple/Google on average every 4.5 mins.
> The phone IMEI, hardware serial number, SIM serial number and IMSI,
> handset phone number etc are shared with Apple and Google. Both iOS
> and Google Android transmit telemetry, despite the user explicitly
> opting out of this. When a SIM is inserted both iOS and Google Android
> send details to Apple/Google. iOS sends the MAC addresses of nearby
> devices, e.g. other handsets and the home gateway, to Apple together
> with their GPS location. Users have no opt out from this and currently
> there are few, if any, realistic options for preventing this data
> sharing."

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about OCSP. You linked to phone telemetry. Please read the question body to understand the context for the title of the question.

Comment: Also, "share some stuff" isn't very helpful. There are very different operating systems.